# How to add EXIF Lens data in Lightroom for unknown lens?

Tags: metadata, lightroom-4, lightroom-catalog, exiftool

One of my prime lenses is non-electronic and so the photos EXIF data does not include any lens information. These show up in Lightroom 4.3 as "Unknown".

I see no way through Lightroom to add this lens name, focal length, etc. The photos are spread across folders, so doing it manually with an EXIF like this one will not work https://exiftool.org/

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lightroom Upgrade vs Lens Metadata](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/lightroom-upgrade-vs-lens-metadata)

Comment: @DanWolfgang - I don't think it's truly a dupe. It's not about rebuilding information that was already there. There's a secondary question there, but it's likely to be missed by somebody with his problem (not an uncommon one, I think, manual lenses are gaining popularity).

Comment: @DanWolfgang - I saw that post, but it didn't help. The answer provided here was perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you have good scripting skills, EXIFTool can be made to do this across folders. However, there is a donation-ware plug-in for Lightroom called [LensTagger](http://www.essl.de/wp/software/lenstagger-lightroom-plugin/) that may do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I am comfortable with scripting but was hoping not to have to, and I quite like donate-ware.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X you can use Exif Editor (http://www.exifeditorapp.com/) from Martin Novak to edit lens data.

It's just an interface to [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), but it's well designed and lets you define some templates and work on batches fo shots, so you can change or add exif metadata in bulk.

I use it often to add lens metadata to shots taken with manual ("vintage") lenses.

Comment: Update: Exif Editor is not longer free, but a staggering £10 on mac App Store.

Comment: Right, it's not free, but I think it worth it, especially if you work a lot with manual lenses. Sure, you can always add metadata from the cli with `exiftool`, but the process is a lot quicker with Exif Editor.