# Prevent Lightroom from discarding lens model from EXIF

Tags: lightroom, metadata

I recently got a Tokina 10-17 mm F mount. Lightroom does not seem to be able to automatically recognize this lens based on NEF files.  It does not automatically find the correct lens model for distortion correction (when enabled) and it does not include the lens model in the EXIF of exported JPEGs.  All this despite the fact that ExifTool does show the correct model under the "Lens ID" tag in the NEF files.

Is there a way to get Lightroom to include the lens model in exported JPEGs?

---

Why is this question different from [How to add EXIF Lens data in Lightroom for unknown lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37653/10147) In that question the lens model is completely unknown to Lightroom, and is not included at all in the original NEFs.  In my case it is included in the NEFs (it' a "CPU lens"), and the lens model is already known to Lightroom in the sense that it can be manually selected for distortion correction purposes (in fact simply selecting the manufacturer allows Lightroom to find the correct model).  It is not clear to me if this makes a difference.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Lightroom?

Comment: @inkista Yes, version 2015.5.

Comment: There is a bug in 2015.5 (maybe earlier not sure) that prevents NEF's from showing the correct lens.  That bug (e.g. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2131686) does not prevent it from showing the lens correction profiles, so you may have a different issue, but mentioning this just in case it is the recognition bug for NEF's.

Comment: @Linwood You are correct.  It is that bug.  The information is missing for *all* lenses, not just this Tokina, but I didn't realize this ...  If you write it as an answer, I'll accept.  Or maybe I should just delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in 2015.5 (maybe earlier not sure) that prevents NEF's from showing the correct lens. [Here's one description at Adobe](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/2131686). Generally this does not prevent correct selection of lens profiles, at least it did not for me, it is a visibility issue mostly.  At the end of that thread is a link to the (very terse) bug report saying they hope for a fix next version.

Comment: Adobe has released a fix that should address this now: http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2016/04/lightroom-cc-2015-5-1-now-available.html